# Não consigo fazer o butão funcionar, ja tentei onclick e addEventListerner

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando colocar um botão delete nos elementos 'li' (isso funciona), e tentando usar o `removeChild()` mas estou recebendo:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: removeChild is not defined

Então para ver se está funcionando eu mudei o `removeChild()` para a função log, e agora a função log aparece no console quando pressiono o subButton e não quando clico no botão delete.

```js
function action() {

  let item = document.createElement('li');
  let inputValue = document.getElementById('tasks').value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  item.appendChild(t);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("you must write something!");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('myUl').appendChild(item);
  }
  document.getElementById('tasks').value = '';

  const tasksDelete = document.createElement("button");
  tasksDelete.classList.add("delete");
  tasksDelete.innerHTML = 'X';
  item.appendChild(tasksDelete);
  document.getElementsByClassName("delete").onclick = log();
  //document.getElementsByClassName("delete").addEventListener("click", log());

  function log() {
    console.log("name")
  }
  //tasksDelete.document.getElementById('myUl');
  //tasksDelete.removeChild();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>TO-DO LIST</h2>
  <input type="text" id="tasks" class="List" placeholder="add">
  <input type="submit" id="subButton" onclick="action()">
  <!-- <button type="button" id='resetBut' onclick="deleteIl()">Reset</button>-->
  <div>
    <ul id="myUl"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode adicionar o evento `click` no elemento salvo na constante `tasksDelete` que você já criou, e dentro desse evento você só precisa chamar o método `remove` para a variável `item`

```js
tasksDelete.addEventListener('click', function () {
  item.remove();
});
```

Seu exemplo completo funcionando:

```js
function action() {
  let item = document.createElement('li');
  let inputValue = document.getElementById('tasks').value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  item.appendChild(t);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("you must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('myUl').appendChild(item);
  }
  document.getElementById('tasks').value = '';

  const tasksDelete = document.createElement("button");
  tasksDelete.classList.add("delete");
  tasksDelete.innerHTML = 'X';
  tasksDelete.addEventListener('click', function() {
    item.remove();
  });
  item.appendChild(tasksDelete);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>TO-DO LIST</h2>
  <input type="text" id="tasks" class="List" placeholder="add">
  <input type="submit" id="subButton" onclick="action()">
  <!-- <button type="button" id='resetBut' onclick="deleteIl()">Reset</button>-->
  <div>
    <ul id="myUl"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: andré walker, muito obrigada, só um duvida poderia me dizer sobre o function() no eventListener? a que função esta se referindo, mais uma vezmuitíssimo obrigada.

Comment: o método `addEventListener` recebe no segundo parâmetro uma função de callback que será chamada sempre que o evento ocorrer. Essa função pode já existir no código, ou pode ser informada uma [Função anônima](https://ricardo-reis.medium.com/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-an%C3%B4nimas-javascript-92361075fd89)